# What is the number of arrangements of 5 different things taken 3 at a time in which 2 particular thing always occur?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know , there is formula to apply, s!*(r-s+1)*( n-s P k-s).

I tried with example, 
n=5 ; r=3 and s=2. 
I'm getting answer as 2!*(3-2+1)*3 = 2*2*3 = **12**.

But, if I solve manually with example, 
consider n = {1,2,3,4,5}
then possible arrangements are as follows:

145
154
245
254
345
354
415
425
435
451
452
453
514
524
534
541
542
543.
Total count is **18**. 
Where am I going wrong

Comment: I'm referring this for formula: number 5 (b).                                                                                https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Id7XEmXzZNAC&pg=SA1-PA40&lpg=SA1-PA40&dq=the+number+of+permutation+of+n+different+things+taken+r+at+a+time+when+s+things+are+to+be+always+included&source=bl&ots=DtCTmNkzdB&sig=F2ret8rN8w30cVcF2Xp9PjDmu9o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-4o-Z-PvcAhXCdysKHQvHAOw4ChDoATADegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=the%20number%20of%20permutation%20of%20n%20different%20things%20taken%20r%20at%20a%20time%20when%20s%20things%20are%20to%20be%20always%20included&f=false

Comment: A suggestion... stop trying to search for *formulas* and trying to memorize different formulas for different situations.  Instead, learn *methods* and *strategies*.  This problem is easily approachable using the multiplication principle (a.k.a. rule of product).

Comment: yea, thanks for the suggestion. Can you please help me out with this problem.

Comment: The answers below already do a fine job of explaining the solution using multiplication principle.  The general solution again being "pick what other numbers are used" followed by "pick how they are arranged."  This can be done in $\binom{n-s}{r-s}\cdot r!$ ways, but again this formula should not be memorized since you can always just rederive it on the spot whenever it is needed.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is designed in a way such that it only accounts for permutations, where the chosen fixed elements appear together i.e. as a block. For example, in your case $451$ is allowed, whereas $415$ is not because $4$ and $5$ are the chosen elements. If you count only those, there are indeed $12$ of them.

The formula that deals with what you want is $r!{n-s \choose r-s}$. In this case, the number would be $3!{3 \choose 1}=18$, exactly what you got.

Comment: You mean to say, 12 is when '4','5' are coming together?

Comment: @RatnakarChinchkar Yeah. I meant exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to view your link, but here is how I would calculate it:

You are looking for your arrangement to contain both 4 and 5. So, choose one more number (from the remaining 3). Then permute the three numbers. My guess (and this is a guess) is that the formula you are looking at has something to do with multisets.

Anyway, choosing the third number, then permuting the three numbers would give you this calculation:

$$\dbinom{3}{1}3! = 3\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 18$$

which agrees with the number of arrangements you found by writing every one out.

Comment: Interstellarprobe  and SinTan , thank you guys.  I'm trying to test formula : Number of permutation of n different things, taken r at a time, when s particular things are to be always included in each arrangement is ,
s! * (r-(s-1)) * n-s P r-s. In my case n = {1,2,3,4,5} and s= {4,5}. r=3.

Comment: @Ratnakar Yes, if the 4 and the 5 must be adjacent, the answer is 12. Demonstration: $$\begin{matrix}145 \\ 154 \\ 245 \\ 254 \\ 345 \\ 354 \\ 451 \\ 541 \\ 452 \\ 542 \\ 453 \\ 543\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Yea, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

2 necessary items may be placed in 3P2 ways
And remaining 1item out of 3 items in 3! Ways
Hence answer =3P2*3P1=3*3!=18

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).